# Random value comming out of nowhere with vector

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to make a matrix graph with cpp, which turns out it's quite a chalange. So to make a matrix I use tewo nested vectors:

```
class Graph{
        private:
                vector<vector<int> > matr;
                int number_vertc;
        public:
                Graph(int = 0);
                void print_graph();
};
```

After that in the cpp file I have this:

```
void Graph::print_graph(){
        cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<number_vertc;i++){
                for(int j=0; j < number_vertc; j++){
                        cout << matr[i][j];
                        cout << "|";
                }
                cout << "|" << endl; 
        }
}
Graph::Graph(int n){
        number_vertc=n;
        matr.resize(n);
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
                matr[i].resize(n);
        }
}
```

With the first function I aim to print the matrix, which in out case should always be containing 0 and it almost does but here is the result:

```
marton@linux-clwa:~/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/dm/graphs/cpp> make
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c graph.cpp
g++  main.o graph.o -o output
marton@linux-clwa:~/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/dm/graphs/cpp> ./output 
ahdhasd
----------------------------
53|0|0|0|0||
0|0|0|0|0||
0|0|0|0|0||
0|0|0|0|0||
0|0|0|0|0||
```

For some reason the first value of the matrix is 53, why does this happen and how to fix it?

PS. this is not the full code, to see everything, check this:

https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/fmi-fall-2016/tree/master/dm/graphs/cpp

Comment: Please **manufacture** [mcve]. I won't go to some external source just to investigate your problem. On the topic of which: did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Possibly not the issue, but in `Graph::Graph()`, `i<=n` should be `i<n`.

Comment: Thank you aschepler, that was the problem, please add an aswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an out-of-bounds access of the vector:

```
 matr.resize(n);
 for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){  // <-- Loop goes to n, which is out-of-bounds
      matr[i].resize(n);
```

On the last iteration, you're accessing `matr[n]`, which is out of bounds.  The correction would be:

```
 matr.resize(n);
 for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
      matr[i].resize(n);
```

Instead of a loop, you could have done the following:

```
 matr = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

Or:

```
matr.resize(n);
std::for_each(matr.begin(), matr.end(), [&](auto& v){ v.resize(n); });
```

Or:

```
Graph::Graph(int n) : matr(n, std::vector<int>(n)), number_vertc(n) {}
```

In addition, if you used [std::vector::at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `operator []`, an `std::out_of_range` exception would have been thrown instead of your program running with undefined behavior occurring.  Thus you would (or should have) detected the problem much earlier.

```
 matr.resize(n);
 for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){ 
      matr.at(i).resize(n);  // <-- std::out_of_range exception
```

---

To add, I would suggest not to introduce variables such as `number_vertc`, since a `std::vector` knows its own size by calling the `vector::size()` function.  Introducing extraneous variables that determine the size can only get you into trouble if you resize the vector, and you forget to update that variable.